# How to scrape a web page with dynamic content added by JavaScript?

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape [this webpage](https://clnk.in/nwU6), it have lazy load as we scroll it gets loaded. Using Nokogiri I am able to scrape the initial page, but not the rest of the page which load after scrolling.

Comment: You can take a help of selenium-webdriver too. By which you can scroll it down and also grab the information by using selenium-webdriver. or scroll using selenium,and scrap using nokogiri.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get lazy loaded page, scrap the following pages:

```
http://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/shoes/casual-shoes/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dpopularity&sid=osp%2Ccil%2Cnit%2Ce1f&start=31&ajax=true
http://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/shoes/casual-shoes/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dpopularity&sid=osp%2Ccil%2Cnit%2Ce1f&start=46&ajax=true
http://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/shoes/casual-shoes/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dpopularity&sid=osp%2Ccil%2Cnit%2Ce1f&start=61&ajax=true
...
```

---

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'
require 'open-uri'

number = 1
while true
  url = "http://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/shoes" +
        "/casual-shoes/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dpopularity&" +
        "sid=osp%2Ccil%2Cnit%2Ce1f&start=#{number}&ajax=true"

  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(doc.at_css('#ajax').text)

  products = doc.css(".browse-product")
  break if products.size == 0

  products.each do |item|
    title = item.at_css(".fk-display-block,.title").text.strip
    price = (item.at_css(".pu-final").text || '').strip
    link = item.at_xpath(".//a[@class='fk-display-block']/@href")
    image = item.at_xpath(".//div/a/img/@src")

    puts number
    puts "#{title} - #{price}"
    puts "http://www.flipkart.com#{link}"
    puts image
    puts "========================"

    number += 1
  end
end
```

Comment: When I am scrapping particular URL it is not scrapping anyone

Comment: @shamshul2007, The URLs in my answer may have different format from the original url. So you should investigate that pages.

Comment: ,able to get the url                       http://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/shoes/casual-shoes/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dpopularity&sid=osp%2Ccil%2Cnit%2Ce1f ,but not the rest of the part,I and try to get it done in test.rb file not it ROR application,is that the problem

Comment: @shamshul2007, As I said in previous comment, the format may be different. Could you post the code you tried? And please elaborate what you want get from that pages.

Comment: I am trying to scrap [link]http://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/shoes/casual-shoes/pr?sid=osp,cil,nit,e1f in the following format name of the product: Price of the product: URL of the Product: URL of the product image: In a page there are 15 product and rest of the product is in ajax format means as we scroll down the products get loaded so I am not able to scrap all the products in the required format the code is at [link]pastebin.com/RTgFdyay

Comment: Thanks it solve the problem but the product get duplicated as in every page there are 15 products but it display 30 products for every page.

Comment: @shamshul2007, Replaced `.gu4,.browse-product` with `.browse-product`. Now duplicated products are gone.

Comment: @falsetru can you please answer this question as well   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336599/web-scraping-using-ajax-through-mechanizenokogiriruby